# Compile actionscript using mxmlc compiler

Tags: actionscript-3, command-line, compilation, mxmlc

How would you compile actionscript code whose main class is inside a package using mxmlc command line compiler? Consider the following -

```
com.nuaavee::MainClass
com.nuaavee.utility::SomeUtility
```

`MainClass` imports `SomeUtility` class.

Is there a way to compile these classes keeping `MainClass` as the main class to generate a swf?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution that has been tested to work -

```
mxmlc -output main.swf src/com/nuaavee/MainClass.as -source-path src/
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a Utility class, it should be compiled inside the MainClass.swf as long as it's referenced. i.e. import SomeUtility;

If SomeUtility is actually another swf, you can compile it as a module to load in and out of your MainClass, but that's more complex.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I am not worried about how the classes are organized and loaded. My concern is to be able to compile the swf. Please let me know if you know how.

Comment: mxmlc.exe -options targetClass.as

Comment: mxmlc.exe will automatically include the needed supclasses.